# How to let the user fill in the "Recipient" field of the contact form?

Tags: 8, entities, forms

I created a new type of contact form. It is called "Invitation".

The problem is that the recipient field does not appear and it is not editable.

I want the user to fill in the recipient's email to send invitations.

How to let the user fill in the "Recipient" field of the contact form ?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if the "contact form" functionality is a proper fit for an invitation form.

Comment: @baikho Why can't the contact form do this? I just need to edit the "Recipient" field and create a TWIG template to create an invitation email. The user fills in the destination with an address and clicks "Send".

Comment: Maybe have a look at the Webform module to build your own contact form the way you need it. I think it already comes with the option to submit the form to an email address from user input (which could be a select, radios or just a textfield I think).

Comment: Another alternative would be to provide your own custom module to alter the contact form and the submit function.

Comment: This contact form will be unique and accessible by authenticated users and with a special role

Answer (score 1):

The recipient isn't a Drupal field so I don't think this can be done without custom coding.

This is probably to guard against using the form for spamming. If the recipient field were accessible to anonymous users, then anyone could use the form to send unsolicited emails.